# How increase max message size for OkHttpChannelBuilder?

Tags: android, grpc

I'm catch RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED error and I don't find information about increasing size in OkHttpBuilder.
How increase it?

Comment: There is [`OkHttpChannelBuilder#maxInboundMessageSize(...)`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/okhttp/OkHttpChannelBuilder.html#maxInboundMessageSize-int-).

Comment: @voidzcy, i'm try set it, but error anyway exist

Comment: Can you describe more about your use case?